# looking for something like "array_and"

Tags: php

I'm want to check an array like this, if every value is "true"

```
$arr = array(true, true, true)   // would be true
$arr = array(true, true, false)  // would be false
$arr = array(false, true, false) // would be false
```

PHP provides a funcion "array_sum()". Is there a short function like "array_and()"

Currently I use something like that:

```
$result = true;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  $result = $result && $item;
}
```

Is there any shorter solution?

Comment: Look through the manual. If there isn't one, write one. Next.

Comment: doesn't `in_array(false, $arr, true)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array_product](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php) would work just fine for you.

What? A dirty hack? Well, this is the php way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are ANDing the array contents.  If that is the case you need only ask if false occurs anywhere in the array.  So:

```
$result=in_array(false, $arr,true);
```

Comment: Turn on STRICT mode with the third flag, or you'll get a loose comparison only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you could use `in_array("false")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = array(true, true, false);

if(in_array(false, $foo)) { 
    echo 'false is present'; 
}
```

could be one option unless i'm missing something